# how to know if an IWebDriver's browser is still open?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have an `IWebDriver` object which goes on a site with a message box.

I have to be able to know if the browser is closed.

I used to check a property of the `IWebDriver`, like `URL`, or `title`.

It doesn work because the function throw an exception because it timeout.

However, if I have a message box, the browser is constantly loading the page, thus I get a timeout too... but browser is not closed.

How can I know if it's just loading indefinitely, or really closed?
Could I close the message box (with code)?

Here is the code to initialise the driver:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
                        capabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile.ToBase64String());
string browserName = browserNameFF;

IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(remoteAddress), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
```

Then to check if it timeout

```
try
{
strint title = driver.title;
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code and how you are initializing the WebDriver.

Comment: done, I show they way I check if it timeouts, but it timeout if browser is closed or if browser is in a timeout

Comment: What's wrong with calling `Close()` on it?

Comment: We need to know when we have a timeout the reason.
If we close it, there is no way to know if it was timing out or if someone closed it for example.
Without giving all the boring details, we need to differentiate between both.